# Orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{F})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, orthonormal

Let $\{e_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{F})$ with $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that the collection
\begin{equation}
\{e_{k,j}\}_{k,j\in \mathbb{N}} \qquad \mbox{where} \qquad e_{k,j}(x,y):=e_k(x)e_j(y)
\end{equation}
gives an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\mathbb{F})$.

**My idea:**

I know that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e_k(x)\overline{e_j(x)}dx=\delta_{k,j}
\end{equation}
so I can write:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} e_{k,j}(x,y)\overline{e_{h,l}(x,y)}d(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e_{k}(x)\overline{e_h(x)}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e_j(y)\overline{e_{h}(y)}dy)dx
\end{equation}
that is equal to $1$ if $k=h$ and $j=l$, equal to $0$ otherwise. Hence $\{e_{k,j}\}_{k,j\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a orthonormal system of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\mathbb{F})$.

Now, to prove the completeness I use the maximality condition of $\{e_{k\}_{k}\in \mathbb{N}}$:
\begin{equation}
0=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} f(x,y)\overline{e_{k,j}(x,y)}d(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}F_k(y)\overline{e_j(y)}dy
\end{equation}
so $F_k=0$ for the maximality condition of $\{e_{k\}_{k}\in \mathbb{N}}$, that implies $f=0$. I can conclude that $\{e_{k,j}\}_{k,j\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: How do you know that $f = 0$ follows from $F_{k} = 0$ for each $k$?  This seems to be a jump.

Comment: We have $F_k=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x,y)\overline{e_k(x)} dx$ for all $k$ so, the only way to get $F_k=0$ is that $f=0$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the statement "$F_{k} = 0$ for each $k$ implies $f = 0$"?  That's a statement that requires proof, hence my original comment.